# How can i get the Health Status of a Azure app service certificate?

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service in Azure configured with Private Key Certificate.

When i browse in Azure there is one that says Warning and will expire in Dec 2022 and there is another that is Healthy and expires in Dec 2023.

I am using the following to retrieve certificates

```
az webapp config ssl list --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

But i cant see in the respones where i can check for "Healthy"  or "Warning" Health Status .
How can i check this ?

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to achieve your requirement following the below powershell script.

```
$ExpirationDate=$(az webapp config ssl list --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --query "[].[expirationDate]" --output table)
$CertificateName=$(az webapp config ssl list --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --query "[].[keyVaultSecretName]" --output table)

$CurrentDate=date +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00"

for($i = 2; $i -lt $ExpirationDate.length; $i++){ 
    $Difference = $(date -d $ExpirationDate[$i] +%s) - (date -d $CurrentDate +%s)
    $Result = $Difference/(60*60*24)
    if($Result -le 90){
        Write-Host -NoNewline "The" $CertificateName[$i] "--> WARNING" `n`
    }
    else{
        Write-Host -NoNewline "The" $CertificateName[$i] "--> HEALTHY" `n`
    }
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

**NOTE:** Here, I'm attempting to read the certificate's expiration date and print manually whether or not it will soon expire in requested time frame. In my situation, I've given myself a 90-day window.

#### UPDATE

Here is the updated code that was working for me using `Get-Date`.

```
$ExpirationDate=$(az webapp config ssl list --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --query "[].[expirationDate]" --output table)
$CertificateName=$(az webapp config ssl list --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME> --query "[].[keyVaultSecretName]" --output table)

$CurrentDate=Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00"

for($i = 2; $i -lt $ExpirationDate.length; $i++){ 
    $Difference = $(date -d $ExpirationDate[$i] +%s) - (date -d $CurrentDate +%s)
    $Result = $Difference/(60*60*24)
    if($Result -le 90){
        Write-Host -NoNewline "The" $CertificateName[$i] "--> WARNING" `n`
    }
    else{
        Write-Host -NoNewline "The" $CertificateName[$i] "--> HEALTHY" `n`
    }
}
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

Comment: Do the certificates need to be stored in a Vault in Azure? If so i dont store them there.

Comment: @Tracey I'm importing key vault certificates to my webapp and fetching the results from there.

Comment: what is date, I get an error Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00" to type "System.DateTime". Error: 
"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: `date` gives us the current time stamp and the `+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+00:00` converts into the mentioned format. please check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/5tHGgUS.png)

Comment: im aware of the date but I cant seem to use date , i need Get-Date

Comment: You can use `Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+00:00"`. https://i.imgur.com/YCtEbzN.png

Comment: so do you mind changing the above script to incorporate the Get-Date, ive tried and get errors: Get-Date : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+%s'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249716/discussion-between-swethakandikonda-and-tracey).